# How can we join two points with a small ruler?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-constructions

We want to join by a line two distinct points $A$ and $B$. We have only a ruler of length $l>0$ and a pen. If $AB>l$ how can we do this? Imagine a method that works when $AB$ is really huge and we cannot draw a line close to $B$.

Comment: I don't think this is a silly question; "obviously" the answer is that this is impossible, but proving it is not so simple.

Comment: It can be done using the Desargues theorem. Is the reason of the downvotes the fact that it is not exactly research level?

Comment: @Daniel Soltesz. How?

Comment: @NoahS: it is possible! A solution is explained, for instance, in Yaglom's book "Geometric Transformations"; in English translation it is in vol.III I think (in Russian original that I remember well it is vol.2).

Comment: I can answer you if they migrate this to math.stackexchange.

Comment: Maybe the rules need to be made a little more clear. My interpretation is that whenever we have two points in the plane of distance at most $\ell$, we are allowed to draw the line segment between them, and that's it.  But this means that if we are given precisely two points with distance greater than $\ell$, then we are not allowed to do anything, so the construction is not only impossible but clearly impossible.  Obviously others are not interpreting the question this way...so I wonder what they have in mind.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark My interpretation differs from yours: given any point $A$ you are allowed to draw any segment through $A$ of total length less than or equal to $\ell$. So in principle you can start by joining the two points $A$ and $B$ by a polygonal path of lenghts less than $\ell$ and then try to construct the points of intersections between $AB$ and this path.

Comment: @Reimundo: Well, I still don't get it.  *Which* line segments through $A$ of length at most $\ell$ are we allowed to draw?  If we are allowed to draw all of them then obviously we can solve the problem.  If we are only allowed to draw segments when we already have both of the endpoints, then obviously we cannot solve the problem.  So it must be somewhere in between...?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark We can put other points on the plane and can connect them and $A$ with a line if they are of a distance at most $l$. The problem is that we can not aim effectively this way. It would need an infinite amount of tries.

Comment: @Daniel: Sorry, I still don't get it.  In classical Euclidean constructions, we begin by saying exactly what we can do: given any two distinct points, we can construct the line they determine.  Given distinct points P and Q, we can draw the circle centered at P and with radius $|P-Q|$.  That's it.  In this situation, in what manner are we allowed to "put other points on the plane"?

Comment: @DanielSoltész Thanks for the comment, with Desargues' theorem the construction is trivial. I didn't know this particular statement and I'm happy that I learned something today from this question!

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I think,you are allowed to draw a random line through a point and it is enough to give a construction algorithm that works with probability 1 (which usually means that you have just to avoid a finite number of exceptions).

Comment: @Lennart: Thanks.  After reflection I think it is meant to be implicit that we can really start with a polygonal path from $A$ to $B$ and our task is to straighten it.  I suppose I have been rather obtuse about this (but I still wish it had been made more explicit; why not?).

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I prefer to think about it that we have an epsilon of room when placing the ruler on a single point. We can aim at any other point, but there will be an epsilon error.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I think the usual notion of Euclidean construction allows a certain flexibility in doing "arbitrary" things.  For example, to bisect an angle, I'd start by drawing a circular arc, centered at the angle's vertex, and meeting both of the angle's sides.  The radius of this arc is arbitrary, and there seems to be no way to make it specific unless we're given somewhat more than just the angle to be bisected (meaning its vertex and two rays).

Comment: @DanielSoltész I've also posted the question on stackexchange but I am not satisfied with the solution posted there. I hope you can give me some advice. Thanks a lot! Here it is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042541/how-can-we-draw-a-line

Comment: I have never seen any treatment of Euclidean constructions that uses $\epsilon$ approximations (but I am no expert on this).  It is pretty clear though that you don't need to express things that way.  For instance, you should regard a line as "given" if you have two points on that line.  A circle is "given" by its center and one point.  To bisect an angle, you have to be given the angle, say by an ordered triple of non-colinear points.  Then the usual bisection construction uses no flexibility or "almost": it's all about constructing certain points as the intersection of circles and lines.

Comment: @Bogdan: You might have mentioned sooner that the question had already been posted on math.SE.

Comment: @Bogdan, why are you not satisfied with that solution? It seems fine to me.

Comment: To make this question here answerable, you will have to be more precise about what arbitrary operations are permitted and what are not. You state that “we cannot draw a line close to $B$”, but what is your precise meaning of “cannot” and of “close”? I imagine that it should be possible to choose arbitrary lines at random, and if you do so often enough, you'll end up with one which fits our needs. If this “often enough” is too often, then you'll have to talk about expected number of trials, about probability distributions for arbitrary choices, and so on. Is that what you want to ask?

Comment: Not exactly. I just want a complete justification of the algorithm described by you (I don't see why, if you repeat often enough the algorithm you can draw the line. What makes you say that the distance $AP$ will converge to $0$, or $BP$ is less than $l$?). Imagine there is a complete fog between $A$ and $B$, and you can see only the lines. So you don't even know that $B$ lies inside the angle $\angle{DAC}$. Thanks for your interest. I appreciate your efforts!

Comment: This question appears to be a cross-post of an answered question (answerer on math.SE is responsive too).